# How to move Woocommerce product title above image on single product page?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to move Woocommerce product title above image on single product page?

I've tried codes that i've found online but they're not doing anything. I'm guessing this has to be done from functions.php but nothing I do works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Hi, did you found the answer to this ? I am looking for the same thing, it's interesting this is so important and basic, yet I can't find a solution that works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and eventually after struggling for days, I realised it was a plugin that would not allow the php to work.

Disable all your plugins apart from Woocommerce and the Storefront and then use the php code below in your child theme's functions.php file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 11 );
```

Comment: This worked for me, but now WooCommerce stopped to  Display secondary image on hover. Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by override woo-commerce content-single-product.php from your theme directory. Also you can do it by hook: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately, i'm dyslexix however i've tried all combinations and still not getting the results. I've googled how to move Woocommerce product title above the image and tried but still not getting it. I want to move the product title to > woocommerce_before_single_product_summary
what would be the exact code needed? Thanks once again. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> **Put this code in `functions.php`.**

```
function product_change_title_position() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'product_change_title_position' );
```